# Struggling with improving efficency of this code

Tags: oracle, plsql

QUERY FOR COLUMN INSIDE A VIEW(need for this to work faster)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "ODS"."VW_YARDI_DLR_PROPERTY_INFORMATION" ("SPCODE", "HMY", "SPNAME", "SCITY", "SSTATE", "SCODE", "SBASECURRENCYCODE", "SFUNCTIONALCURRENCYCODE", "UCODE", "SAPCODE", "SBPCODE", "SBPNUM", "SARCODE", "DTPACQUIRE", "DPPRICE", "SSAMESTORE", "DTPDISPOSE", "DSALESPRICE", "DOWNERSHIPPERCENT", "DTSTABILIZATION", "IPROPCOUNT", "IBLDCOUNT", "IBUILDINGS", "SSTATUS", "SENTITYTYPE", "SOWNERSHIPTYPE", "SPROPERTYTYPE", "OPERATIONALSITECODE", "MASTERSITECODE", "SCAMPUS", "SENTITYPARENT", "SCAM", "SCURRENTYEARSTABILIZED", "SNEXTYEARSTABILIZED", "SDIVISION", "SREPORTINGDIVISION", "SREGION", "SMARKET", "SCOUNTRY", "SSTATE2", "SPROPERTYSOURCECURRENCY", "SOWNEDLEASED", "SELT2000", "SHRISBUSINESSGROUP3000", "SHRISDIVISION4000", "STAXTRSSTATUS", "STAXPARENTCATEGORY", "STAXCATEGORY", "STAXCOUNTRY", "SASSETMANAGER", "SDIRECTOR", "SREGIONALMANAGER", "SREALESTATEMANAGER", "SASSISTANTREM", "SPROPERTYASSISTANT", "BINACTIVE", "DTCREATED", "DTLASTMODIFIED")  AS 
  SELECT            p.sCode AS sPCode,
  P.hmy as hmy
,               p.sAddr1 AS sPName  
,               p.sCity AS sCity
,               p.sState AS sState          
,               UPPER(ci.sCode)AS sCode             
,               UPPER(dp.sBaseCurrencyCode) AS sBaseCurrencyCode    
,               UPPER(dp.sFunctionalCurrencyCode) AS sFunctionalCurrencyCode
,               le.uCode AS uCode               
,               ab.sAPCode AS sAPCode           
,               ab.sBPCode AS sBPCode           
,              ab.sBPNum AS     sBPNum          
,               ab.sARCode AS sARCode           
,               p.sAcquire AS dtPAcquire        
,               p.dPPrice AS dPPrice
,CASE 
        WHEN p.sDispose <= SYSDATE
            THEN 'No'
        WHEN TRIM(trailing ' ' from dp.sOwnershipType) = 'Consolidated'
            AND p.sAcquire <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)- 2)||'-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS sSameStore
,                   p.sDispose AS dtPDispose    
,               p.dSalesPrice AS dSalesPrice

,(SELECT            SUM(  COALESCE(ft8.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft7.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft6.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft5.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft4.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft3.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *   COALESCE(ft2.dPercent, 1.00000000000000000000) 
                                                                    *ft1.dPercent * 100.00000000)
                                                    FROM            ODS.YARDI_Property px
                                                    INNER JOIN      ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft1
                                                    ON              px.hMy  =   ft1.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft1.iCategory   =   0
                                                    AND             ft1.dPercent    <>  0
                                                    and         SYSDATE BETWEEN         ft1.dtStart
                                                    AND             nvl(ft1.dtEnd, SYSDATE+1)
                                                         
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft2
                                                    ON              ft1.hInvestment = ft2.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft1.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                                    AND             ft2.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft2.dPercent <> 0
                
                                                    AND             SYSDATE
                                                    BETWEEN         ft2.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft2.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                    
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft3 
                                                    ON               ft2.hInvestment = ft3.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft2.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                                    AND             ft3.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft3.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE 
                                                    BETWEEN         ft3.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft3.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                   
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft4 
                                                    ON              ft3.hInvestment = ft4.hInvestor
                                                    AND         ft3.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                                    AND             ft4.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft4.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE
                                                    BETWEEN         ft4.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft4.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                  
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft5 
                                                    ON                ft4.hInvestment = ft5.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft4.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                                    AND             ft5.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft5.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE 
                                                    BETWEEN         ft5.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft5.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                   
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft6 
                                                    ON              ft5.hInvestment <> P.hMy
                                                    AND             ft5.hInvestment = ft6.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft6.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft6.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE 
                                                    BETWEEN         ft6.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft6.dtEnd,SYSDATE)
                                                  
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft7 
                                                    ON              ft6.hInvestment = ft7.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft6.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                                    AND             ft7.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft7.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE 
                                                    BETWEEN         ft7.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft7.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                   
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft8 
                                                    ON              ft7.hInvestment = ft8.hInvestor
                                                    AND             ft7.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
                                                    AND             ft8.iCategory = 0
                                                    AND             ft8.dPercent <> 0
                                                    AND             SYSDATE 
                                                    BETWEEN         ft8.dtStart
                                                    AND             COALESCE(ft8.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
                                                 
                                                    wHERE   --P.HMY>4643
                                                        trim(trailing ' ' from lower(px.sCode)) =   'rdrtinc'
                                                    AND         
                                                   p.hMy IN
                                                                                (
                                                                                    SELECT FT8.hInvestment  from    dual                        
                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT7.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT6.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT5.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT4.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT3.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT2.hInvestment  FROM    dual

                                                                                    UNION   ALL

                                                                                    SELECT FT1.hInvestment  FROM    dual
                                                                                
                                                ))
                                                 as dOwnershipPercent
,               dd.dtStabilization AS dtStabilization           
,               dd.iPropCount AS iPropCount 
,                               dd.iBldCount AS iBldCount       
,       (SELECT COUNT(b.hMy)FROM    ODS.YARDI_Building b WHERE  P.hMy   =   b.hProp) AS         iBuildings      
,               atr.SubGroup27 AS sStatus
,               atr.SubGroup23 AS sEntityType
,               trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup6) AS sOwnershipType 
,                   trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup3) AS sPropertyType  
,                   trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup75) as OperationalSiteCode 
,                   trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup76) as MasterSiteCode 
,               atr.SubGroup70 AS sCampus   
,               atr.SubGroup34 AS sEntityParent         
,               atr.SubGroup35 AS   sCAM                        
,                   atr.SubGroup32 AS sCurrentYearStabilized    
,               atr.SubGroup33 AS sNextYearStabilized           
,               atr.SubGroup11 AS sDivision             
,           atr.SubGroup38 AS   sReportingDivision
,               trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup1) AS sRegion    
,               trim(trailing ' ' from atr.SubGroup2) AS sMarket                        
,               atr.SubGroup30 AS sCountry                      
,               atr.SubGroup31 AS sState2                       
,               atr.SubGroup18 AS   sPropertySourceCurrency 
,                           atr.SubGroup29 AS sOwnedLeased  
,       atr.SubGroup26  AS  sELT2000                        
,                   atr.SubGroup15 AS sHRISBusinessGroup3000    
,       atr.SubGroup14 AS       sHRISDivision4000               
,               atr.SubGroup36 AS  sTaxTRSStatus                    
,   atr.SubGroup69 AS           sTaxParentCategory          
,       atr.SubGroup37 AS           sTaxCategory                
,           atr.SubGroup39 AS       sTaxCountry             
,           atr.SubGroup71  AS  sAssetManager               
,                           atr.SubGroup20 AS   sDirector       
,                   atr.SubGroup21 AS sRegionalManager          
,               atr.SubGroup22 AS sRealEstateManager            
,                               atr.SubGroup24 AS sAssistantREM 
,                       atr.SubGroup25 AS sPropertyAssistant
,   CASE  when p.bInActive = - 1
                                                THEN    'Yes'
                                                ELSE    ''
                                                END AS bInactive
,               p.dtCreated AS dtCreated
,                   p.dtLastModified AS dtLastModified
FROM            ODS.YARDI_Property p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Country_Info ci
ON              p.hCountry = ci.hMy
INNER JOIN      ODS.VW_YARDI_DLR_PROPERTY dp
ON              p.hMy = dp.hProp
--left outer join YardiDaily.dbo.LockOut l on p.hMy = l.hProp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Attributes atr 
ON              p.hMy = atr.h_Prop
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_OWNER le
ON              p.hLegalEntity = le.hMyPerson
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT          px.hMy AS hProp
                    ,               ap.sCode AS sAPCode
                    ,               bp.s_Code AS sBPCode
                    ,                   SUBSTR(TRIM(trailing ' ' from bp.s_Acct_Num),-5) AS sBPNum
                    ,               ar.sCode AS sARCode
                    /*--,               br.sCode sBRCode,
                    --,             right(br.sAcctNum, 5) sBRNum*/
                    FROM            ODS.YARDI_Property px
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Acct ap 
                    ON  (ap.hMy,PX.hMy) in (
                                                    SELECT  po.h_Value,po.h_Prop
                                                    FROM    ODS.YARDI_Prop_Options po
                                                    WHERE   1=1--PX.hMy     =   po.h_Prop
                                                    AND     po.s_Type   =   'hPayableCashAcct'
                                                    AND coalesce(po.h_Value,0) <> 0
                                                )
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Bank_XRef bxp ON pX.hMy   =   bxp.hPpty
                    AND             ap.hMy  =   bxp.h_Acct
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Bank bp 
                    ON              bxp.hBaidx  =   bp.hMy
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Acct ar
                    ON              (ar.hMy,px.hmy) in  (
                                                    SELECT  po.h_Value,po.h_Prop
                                                    FROM    ODS.YARDI_Prop_Options po
                                                    WHERE   1=1--X.hMy      =   po.h_Prop
                                                    AND     po.s_Type   = 'hReceiptCashAcct'
                                                    AND   coalesce(po.h_Value, 0) <> 0
                                                )
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Bank_XRef bxr 
                    ON              px.hMy  =   bxr.hPpty
                    AND             ar.hMy  =   bxr.h_Acct
                    --left outer join YardiDaily.dbo.Bank br on bxr.hBaidx = br.hMy
                    WHERE           px.iType    =   3

                ) ab
ON              p.hMy = ab.hProp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Propbut_DLR_Data dd ON p.hMy = dd.hCode
AND                (dd.dtEffective,p.hmy)    in    (
                                        SELECT    MAX(x.dtEffective),x.hCode
                                        FROM    ODS.YARDI_Propbut_DLR_Data x
                                        WHERE    1=1 -- and P.hMy = x.hCode
                                        --AND        x.dtEffective <= DATEADD(SECOND, - 1, DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE()))
                                     AND        x.dtEffective <=  ((SYSDATE-1)-1/(24*60*60))
                                     group by x.hcode
                                    )
WHERE           p.bInactive =   0
AND             p.iType     =   3;
```

Comment: please format your query in a way so that it is readable here.

Comment: is this not correct way to format ?

Comment: Can you tell us what this is actually trying to do? It looks like a complete rewrite to get rid of all those similar joins would be possible, this would be simpler to do knowing what this is really achieving. You say this is part of a view? How are you joining to it?How many times are you expecting it to run in one execution? Would it be better to run once for many values?

Comment: I may have missed something from your SQL. But I can't see any table alias `P` (as used in `ft1.hInvestment <> P.hMy`). If your SQL is part of a view, is it aliased somewhere outside the code you posted? And are you sure your performance issue is related to this part of the view?

Comment: @FatP yes it is a alias outside as ODS.YARDI_PROPERTY P, yes i think so , because without this the view is very fast.

Comment: So your are not showing us the full picture. And without info about the outer query, it is impossible to help you to tune.

Comment: @FatP now you can see the entire query. Please give some insights

Answer (score 0):

Step 0: remove the scalar sub query.

Scalar sub queries are ran for each row in the result set.

Move it to a CTE (`WITH`) and join with the rest of the query

Answer (score -1):

Several things you can do.

1 - You are putting functions and not equals inside your join. This is not efficient, as it won't be able to take advantage of indexes. You should move them to the **where clause**.

2 - It's best to rewrite a not equal zero (<>0) with two clauses, a greater than zero (>0) and a less than zero (<0). It's a marginal improvement that reduces the query cost.

3 - Try to avoid functions. In your code, the **between function** can be rewritten into greater than and less than, reducing your query cost further.

4 - Make sure you have the correct indexes:

```
ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran >> Compound Index on **hInvestor** and **iCategory**
ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran >> Compound Index on **dPercent**, **dtStart**, **dtEnd**
ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran >> Index on **hInvestment**
ODS.YARDI_Property >> Index on **hMy**
```

Not sure if the query optimizer will use them all. Test to see which ones give you the best impact.

An excerpt from your code:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft2 ON ft1.hInvestment <> P.hMy
    AND ft1.hInvestment = ft2.hInvestor
    AND ft2.iCategory = 0
    AND ft2.dPercent <> 0
    AND SYSDATE BETWEEN ft2.dtStart AND COALESCE(ft2.dtEnd, SYSDATE)
```

I would rewrite it to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.YARDI_Fund_Tran ft2 ON 
    ft1.hInvestment = ft2.hInvestor
    AND ft2.iCategory = 0

WHERE ft1.hInvestment <> P.hMy 
    AND ft2.dPercent > 0
    AND ft2.dPercent < 0
    AND ft2.dtStart >= SYSDATE
    AND COALESCE(ft2.dtEnd, SYSDATE) <= SYSDATE
```

Apply this to every one of your clauses and note the difference.